# How to move subscribers to different MailChimp list (using Gibbon API in Ruby on Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mailchimp, gibbon

In my Ruby on Rails application, I use gibbon API to subscribe member to a list. I want an option where members can be moved from one list to the other.

MailChimp has this option in their website, but can anyone help how to implement this using API?

https://mailchimp.com/help/copy-or-move-subscribers-to-a-list/#move+subscribers

Do I need to individually **delete** from the first list and **add** to the other list or there is any alternative approach?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Not possible. You have to [delete the member](https://developer.mailchimp.com/documentation/mailchimp/reference/lists/members/#delete-delete_lists_list_id_members_subscriber_hash) from a list and then [add a new list member](https://developer.mailchimp.com/documentation/mailchimp/reference/lists/members/#create-post_lists_list_id_members), as you said, in 2 API calls.